# Could my planet be habitable (Or partially habitable) by humans?

Tags: planets, humans, atmosphere, worldbuilding-process, habitability

### Set up

I'm currently building a planet that I want to have both alien life forms and humans. It has the following traits:

- Humans migrated from Earth a long time ago, but only landed on the planet 24 years ago.
- The planet has Earth-like life and humans on it together.
- The planet is about twice as big as the Earth in radius, and is 4 times as massive (I think that's the term in astronomy for having more mass...?), and has 1G gravity (To Earth).
- The planet has 2 stars:
- An F-type star of 1.2 solar masses with about 2.3 billion years left as of current times
- A K-type star of 0.4 solar masses
- The planet orbits the two stars at about 1.6 AU on average.
- The planet has 2 moons:
- 1 around 80% the size of the Earth, orbiting at 238,900 miles away on average.
- 1 28% the size of Earth, orbiting at about 72,527 miles away on average.

I want:

- Humans to be able to live on the surface naturally.

---

### Difficulties in Living

My planet has:

- A global temperature is around 23 Celsius (78 Fahrenheit), with the poles having a typical average of about 10 Celsius (50 Fahrenheit), and the hottest regions (Mostly sun-scorched deserts) having an average of about 54 Celsius (129 Fahrenheit).
- An atmospheric pressure of 144% Earth's at sea level
- Atmosphere:

  - 32% oxygen (a bit over 50% more than modern Earth, but a bit more than 21% less than the Carboniferous period)
  - 67% nitrogen
  - 1% other gases, with atmospheric carbon dioxide level at about 1,600 ppm (In the range of the Cretaceous (1,000-2,000 ppm)). T

---

### History

The temperature and atmospheric composition came to their current values about 12 million years ago, so life on the planet has adapted.

---

### Desired Outcome

I don't care whether humans can breathe on the planet without an oxygen mask. They came well after life evolved, so their ability to breathe isn't my problem, and they have the technology to make their own in my world anyway.

What I want to know is whether humans could live out in the open on this world with nothing more than an oxygen mask. A major concern of mine is the atmosphere, which is, at sea level, about 130% thicker than Earth's, and the temperature. This temperature is around the normal average temperature of Earth during the Paleocene-Eocene Thermal Maximum (PETM), so Earth-like life could survive, and I don't care about ice caps. However, I wanted to know whether humans could survive with only an oxygen mask.

---

### Things To Consider

The atmosphere is thicker, but according to [this](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/10895/maximum-survivable-atmospheric-pressure) question's answer, humans could theoretically survive up to 4 times Earth's atmospheric pressure.

The oxygen levels are likely too high (By how much oxygen %, I don't know).

Maybe the temperatures make the equator too hot for humans to survive in the open all year round, so humans might have to settle more at the poles.

The biochemistry is similar to Earth's, meaning that humans should be able to consume food safely (For those of you who don't know, Earth biochemistry is almost all left-handed amino acids, and they cannot be swapped for right-handed ones).

---

**Could humans survive on this planet in to open with only an oxygen mask?**

Comment: Yes, a ~0.5 bar oxygen partial pressure is pretty toxic for humans. Also, terrible firestorms.

Comment: @biziclop: At 0.5 atm partial pressure oxygen is *maybe* very very mildly toxic; adverse reactions have only been observed with partial pressures of oxygen greater then 0.5 atm, but then nobody knows for sure what happens over an exposure longer than a few days. For short term exposure even 1 atm partial pressure of oxygen is quite safe.

Comment: @AlexP Yes, I meant to live in it all your life. Short exposures to that level are mostly fine. Anyway, I was merely trying to warn OP who mentioned that in the Carboniferous the oxygen percentage in our atmosphere was higher than in the planned atmosphere, that that's only half the story. Percentage AND air pressure multiplied together are what determines whether you've got too much or too little oxygen.

Comment: i cannot imagine those moon orbits beeing stable, you sure those are not supposed to be other planets?

Comment: When you say "global temperature is 23C", what is the range?  Global temperature average on Earth was 13.9C in 2022, but at the moment Accuweather shows Mumbai at 33C and Berlin at 9C (and there are probably hotter places and definitely colder places).  A bit of air-conditioning and some annual migration should make it easily survivable.

Comment: As a former diver, I can say high pressure + high oxygen partial pressure is a no-no. You can live for a few days at high oxygen partial pressures in a low-pressure environment (like the Apollo astronauts did) but people on your planet can only manage to survive by using masks to increase the partial pressure of inert gas (and I bet they need to protect their eyes too). Also with that level of oxygen expect insects to grow large, very large, and b very cautious on making fire.

Comment: @Teh DarkLordeReturns    I have added a lot to my answer on April 6.

Comment: @RonJohn 5  "A planet 80% the size of Earth but 21.2 PSI is... improbable. You need mass to hold gasses to an atmosphere, and Earth's mass is required to hold the amount of gasses in our atmosphere."  Really? Venus has 0.815 times the mass of Earth and a surface pressure 93 times as great.  Titan has 0.0225 the mass of Earth and a surface pressure 1.45 time that of Earth.  I think you should restrict what you write to things that you know, instead of assume, to be correct.

Comment: Your moons are unstable.  The larger one's going to eject the smaller one in short order.

Comment: You're probably going to need to kick one of the stars (probably the little one) out to a really distant orbit, resulting in a boring old fashioned solar system with one really bright, really distant "planet", if you want astronomers to approve of your story. Classic sci-fi "two suns in the sky" binary star systems wouldn't allow for stable orbits.

Comment: While your planet as described is habitable (a bit high oxygen partial pressure, but nothing a bit of genetic engineering cannot fix! well, or masks, but masks are boring), but the issue is that is kinda improbable. Having a habitable planet in a binary system is problematic as orbits gets complicated. Also, your bigger moon is quite big and would drastically impact your orbit - it wouldn't orbit around your planet anymore, but both would orbit around their center of gracity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What are you worried about?

### Is it pressure?

I wouldn't worry about it too much. As someone who has experience diving let me calm your concerns.

It is true that humans are limited to diving at a depth of 10 meters (2 bars, 50% higher) for less than [130 minutes](https://www.naui.org/resources/dive-tables-review/) without requiring decompression. It is not the pressure that limits your time under water but rather the fact that you need to return to a low pressure environment again, and how fast your body absorbs nitrogen (it is also different for different people, 130 minutes is the safe no decompression for most people). As you spend time under high pressure your body dissolves nitrogen into your blood (because the higher pressure of nitrogen allows for more dissolved nitrogen). When you go to a lower pressure the dissolved nitrogen slowly leaves your body. If you have too much dissolved nitrogen, it will form nitrogen bubbles throughout your body causing lots of cellular damage... It is extremely painful, but can be prevented/your life saved by a decompression chamber that will slowly bring your body back to a low pressure environment.

At a 1.44 bar atmosphere you could spend years without much harm (except an increased risk for a [heart attack](https://www.nature.com/articles/news990722-10)). Humans have [spent 73 days](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mission_31#:%7E:text=Fabien%20Cousteau%20also%20hoped%20to,days%202%20hours%2034%20minutes.) at twice that pressure (~3 bar) with no reported negative side effects. Team 31 spent 31 days and were able to safely depressurize in 16 hours.

### Is it the oxygen?

You probably don't need an oxygen mask. Thoough you might want a mask that reduces how much oxygen breathe in, replacing it with

With 144% atmosphere at 33% oxygen == 1.44 bars * .33 = .4752 bars of oxygen, you are below the point where oxygen toxicity starts (0.5 bars partial pressure). Though some people are more sensitive, and others less. I don't know if there is a long term oxygen toxicity exposure.

###### Appendix

Serious mental impairment from Nitrogen narcosis does not set in until a partial pressure of 3.2 bars (there is a lot of variation), though some people have a lower tolerance, and some have a higher. hallucinations occur at 8 bars. At a 1.44 bar atmosphere at 67% you only have .96 bars of nitrogen, which is pretty safe. Very long term exposure might make everyone a little tipsy, I don't know.

Comment: "I don't know if there is a long term oxygen toxicity exposure" - I sort of think there should be, but can't find any supporting evidence either. Maybe where it's used (COPD etc.) its benefits so outweigh any potential detriments that no-one's bothered with it.

Comment: I Know that for saturation diving, there was one company that had a decompression procedure that used a pp of 0.6 to 0.8, because it allowed for a shorter nitrogen off-gassing cycle... So the 0.5 bar cut-off is really taking it safely. (They have since shifted to a more conservative decompression regime).

Comment: @AngryMuppet, my gut says there might be an increased rate of cancer, as low oxygen environments are associated with a significantly lower rate of cancer (naked mole rat research).

Comment: Diving at 10m the pressure is 100% higher, not 50% higher.  Also, when I was diving in the UK in the 70's the dive time was unlimited provided you didn't go below 10m.

Comment: Yes, there is oxygen toxicity at high partial pressures and it varies from getting "drunk" to passing away. One single good side effect: earth bacteria will have a hard time causing infections.

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica Above 10m the lower limit is by the 2 or 3 hours (top) your cylinder can support you (granted you will not make more than a couple of dives on a single day).

Comment: @jean You come up, fit another cylinder and go on another dive.  A 10-minute bob up and down isn't going to affect whether you need a decompression at the very end.

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica 2 bars is ~50% higher than a 1.4 bar atmosphere

Comment: @Jean... Yes, I know there is oxygen toxicity at high partial pressure. I just don't know if there are negative long term effects for exposure to high (but not toxic) oxygen partial pressure.

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica Never tried a "Bob up" and my instructors were adamant against it when diving deeper than 10m. For less than 10m we usually practiced apnea and we can do it all day for many consecutive days without issues. Even in an emergency ascent, we ate taught to do it as calmly and slowly as possible, diving 40m is entirely different than diving less than 10m.

Comment: @Questor What do you mean by "not toxic" oxygen? The difference between medicine and poison is the dosage and for oxygen, that translates as partial pressure*hours exposed.

Comment: @jean  I mean higher oxygen levels than humans are typically exposed to, but lower than cause problems in the short term... We don't know what effects living for a long time in an enriched oxygen environment has on humans... As there hasn't been any research. It could do nothing, it could cause an increased risk of cancer (cuz everything seems to cause cancer)... We don't know.

Comment: @Questor Yes, there are. I remember reading a paper, a very old one, many years ago for the military. The conclusion was in this line: We are wired to work properly on a planet with 1atm, 20~30 celsius, 9.8m/s*s, 60% humidity, and 20% oxygen. Since temperature and humidity can greatly vary we can adapt to changes in it but oxygen and gravity were constant for our ancestors creating no pressure for adaptation in those. We lack the capability to survive the slightest change in such parameters in the long term and even experiments carried out over the range of days can cause permanent harm.

Comment: Cool! do you remember what the paper was called?

Comment: @Questor I wish I can remember. But just remembered another much cooler stuff for your planet. There's a tribe in (india?) lived on diving for generations and they adapted to see underwater and hold their breath for longer. Himalayan people have more pulmonary alveolus while Andes people have slighter bigger lungs. If you can make dozens of generations survive in a hostile environment descendants can adapt.

Answer (score 10):

Wouldn't a mountain counteract the effects of higher air pressure and more oxygen?

[The highest human settlement is about 5 000 metres above sea level](https://earthobservatory.nasa.gov/images/145864/the-highest-settlement-in-the-world#:%7E:text=Tucked%20away%20in%20the%20eastern,sewage%20system%2C%20or%20garbage%20disposal.). That is more than enough to counteract the differences.

[For reference at Mount Everest, the air pressure is around 1/3 of it at sea  level at 8 848 m](https://www.inspiritvr.com/general-chemistry/states-of-matter/air-pressure-at-mount-everest)

---

The humans could start settling the mountains. then they might venture down.

Comment: This sounds like a viable way of thinking about it. It's easy to forget that humans are an exception on Earth, having spread to almost all terrestrial habitats. The norm is very much for organisms to occupy a smaller niche and a small, technologically advanced population of humans could absolutely select the most habitable niche for them. Like older mountains with gentle slopes.

Answer (score 4):

> The planet has 2 moons in an orbit range of around 1.6 AU on average:
>
> 1 around 80% the size of the Earth
>
> 1 28% the size of Earth.

Moons can not orbit habitable planets - that orbit in the habitable zones of their stars - at distances of 1.6 AU.  Such a distance would be many times the Hill radius of the habitable planet.  The gravity of the stars would pull the moon out of orbit around the planet.

You didn't specify the The mass of the planet or its distance from the star.
But there is a relatively narrow range of mass for habitable planets compared to all planets.  There is also a relatively narrow range of mass and luminosity for stars that can have habitable planets compared to all stars.  Thus there is a relatively narrow range of orbital distances within the habitable zones of stars for habitable planets.

And no habitable planet can have a Hill radius of 1.6 AU.

The word "size" in relation to the moons is very vague.  Do you mean radius, surface area, volume, or mass?

Going with radius, a moon with 0.80 the radius of Earth would have 0.512 the mass of Earth (if it had the same average density as Earth) and so it would potentially be habitable for humans if other factors were favorable for habitability.  It would be large enough compared to any planet habitable for humans for the two worlds to be considered to be a double planet.

A world with a radius of 28 percent Earth radius would have a mass of 0.021952 Earth if it had the same average density as Earth. But it would probably be a lot less dense and have a lot less mass.

If the smaller moon had 0.28 the mass of Earth it would have about 0.65 the radius of Earth if it had the same average density.  A world with 0.28 the mass of Earth would potentially be habitable for humans.

So one possible reason for humans to settle on the planet would be to live there for decades, centuries, or millennia while terraforming one or both of the moons to make them habitable for humans and/or native intelligent and/or for non intelligent lifeforms on the planet.

Added April 6, 2023.

The star is said to be an F class star with a mass of 1.2 the mass of the Sun.  According to the table here:

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-type_main-sequence_star#:~:text=An%20F%2Dtype%20main%2Dsequence,between%206%2C000%20and%207%2C600%20K.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-type_main-sequence_star#:%7E:text=An%20F%2Dtype%20main%2Dsequence,between%206%2C000%20and%207%2C600%20K.)

An F7V star should have a mass 1.21 times the mass of he Sun while an F8V star would have a mass 1.18 that of the Sun.

With a luminosity of 2.45 the luminosity of the Sun, the Earth Equivalent distance (EED), where a planet would receive as much radiation as Earth gests from the Sun, of a F7V star would be about 1.565 Astronomical Units (AU).

With a luminosity of 1.95 the luminosity of the Sun, the EED, where a planet would receive as much radiation as Earth gests from the Sun, of a F8V star would be about 1.396 AU.

> A global temperature is around 23 Celsius (78 Fahrenheit), with the poles having a typical average of about 10 Celsius (50 Fahrenheit), and the hottest regions (Mostly sun-scorched deserts) having an average of about 54 Celsius (129 Fahrenheit).

You forgot to convert the temperatures to absolute Kelvin temperatures.

0 degrees Celsius is 273.15 degrees Kelvin.

So the average global temperature would be about 296.15 K, the average polar temperature would be about 283.15 K, and the average tropical temperature would be about 327.15 degrees K.  By contrast the average temperature on Earth is about 15 degrees Celsius, or 288.15 K, or 59 Fahrenheit.

So measured in absolute degrees Kelvin, your planet would be about 1.0277 times as hot as Earth.  So it would have to orbit the star closer than the EED distance to receive more radiation from its star.

I don't know the formula for calculating how much more radiation the planet would have to receive to be 1.0227 times as hot as the Earth.  I think I remember that temperature varies with the fourth power of the energy, so a world with 1.0277 times the temperature would have to recieve about 1.1154892 times as much energy as the Earth.

How close to a star can a planet get before it is too hot for liquid water using life? To find the inner edges of a star's circumstellar habitable zone, or Goldilocks zone, you find the ratio of the star's luminosity divided by the luminosity of the Sun.  Then you find the square root of that ratio and multiply it by the inner edge of the Sun's circumstellar Habitable zone.  Very simple - except for one problem.

According to the list at:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumstellar_habitable_zone#Solar_System_estimates

There have been over a dozen different estimates of the inner or outer Edges of the Sun's habitable zone, or both edges, in the last 60 years.  Some are very different from others.  So which estimate do you choose?

A star can only have habitable planets if it stays on the main sequence phase of its development long enough for a planet to become habitable.

Habitable for human beings and for other oxygen breathers means the planet has to have an oxygen rich atmosphere.  Earth developed a breathable oxygen rich atmosphere about 600 million years ago, when it was about four billion years old.  That oxygen rich atmosphere was produced by photosynthetic plants after non oxygen using lifeforms had existed on Earth for about two or three billion years.

So it should take about four billion years, give or take a billion or two, for a planet with non oxygen using life to produce a breathable oxygen rich atmosphere which humans and multicellular land animals can breathe.

So how long would a spectral class F7V or F8V star with 1.20 the mass of the Sun stay on the main sequence?

This online calculator gives a main sequence lifetime of about 6.33 billion Earth years (6,330,000,000 years).

You wrote:

> An F-type star of 1.2 solar masses with about 2.3 billion years left as of current times.

So the age of the star should be about 6.33 billion minus about 2.3 billion
or about 4 billion years old.  So if the planet's development went at exactly the same rate as Earth's it should be beginning to have an oxygen rich atmosphere as you say.  Maybe it developed a little bit faster than Earth due to various chance events to have such a lot of oxygen so early.